# windows: Laptop does not detect GPU and can not install nvidia drivers after running DDU (display driver uninstaller)

Tags: windows, drivers, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

I wanted to clean the prev installation of nvidia drivers which is why I used DDU. But after using DDU I can not install Nvidia drivers as my laptop refuses to recognize the d-gpu. Any help is greatly appreciated.

What I have tried:

- Re-installing windows using recovery.
- modifying driver installation file nvacig.inf to include hardware id of UHD graphics.
- Resetting BIOS
- Updating BIOS
- Checking for hardware changes after enabling hidden devices in device manager.

Specs :

- Acer AN715-51
- Windows 11
- GTX 1660 ti (notebook)

Screenshot of error while installing nvidia driver:

[image]

GPU not visible in device manager:

[image]

Comment: Try to enter the BIOS, do Reset and reboot. Otherwise, try to boot in Safe mode, run DDU again and reboot normally.

Comment: If the GPU isn't visible in Device Manager, and the CPU's integrated GPU is, the laptop wasn't booted with Discrete Graphics enabled - switch to Discrete Graphics either via the hotkey combination while booted to Windows, or manually select it within the UEFI firmware settings if the laptop supports that.

Comment: @harrymc resetting bios did not work, safe boot and DDU also did not work. Its as if my laptop d gpu has vanished.

Comment: @JW0914 went into the bios but I could not see any option that allows me to select between a dgpu or igpu. Not sure about the hotkeys combination, I looked it up but found nothing for my laptop.

Comment: @Pratyush There has to be a way to manually switch it between integrated and discrete graphics - if nothing else, you may want to reach out to Acer tech support since it's not in the manual either.

Comment: Have you opened the case and touched the GPU card? Perhaps you could try to reseat the card.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone coming to this question here's a reddit thread that answers it:
https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/1aij1o3/comment/kow39q6/?context=3

In short my gpu died.